# Typescript: Objects with a single key

Tags: typescript

Consider the following (partially typed) function:

`const fn = <T, ?? ...>(name: ??, value: T) => ({ [name]: value })`

Is it possible to complete the typing this such that

`fn("hello", someT)`

would have type

`{ hello: T }`?

If not: Is there another approach giving a similar result?

I was thinking of something along the lines of

`<K extends string, T>(name: K, value: T): { [k: K]: T} => ...`

but this does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Use a type parameter to capture the literal type of the key, a subtype of `string`, and use it to define a mapped type

```
const fn = <T, N extends string>(name: N, value: T) => <{[P in N]: T}>({
  [name]: value
});
```

Unfortunately, the type assertion is required.

```
const hasPOfNumber = fn('p', 52);

console.log(hasPOfNumber.p);
```